# Display column values next to each other SQL

Tags: sql, pivot

I have to select which wards have patients with the same last name. I need to display the name of those patients and the IDs that come with them.

My query below works to give me the proper result:-

```sql
SELECT pt.NAME, pt.PATIENTID, pt.PATIENTID
FROM PATIENT pt
WHERE pt.NAME IN
    (SELECT pt.NAME
    FROM PATIENT pt
    GROUP BY pt.NAME
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT pt.WARDNO) < 2)
AND NAME IN
    (SELECT NAME
    FROM PATIENT
    GROUP BY NAME
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

It gives me the following result in the table:

```
Name   |   PatientID
Jones  |   p10
Jones  |   p29
```

However, I want to display my results in the table like this and am not sure how.

```
Name   |   PatientID   |   PatientID
Jones  |   p10         |   p29
```

Comment: You need some sort of pivoting logic here, but my first question for you is what happens if a given name has three patient IDs?  What about four?

Comment: That is another part that I am curious about. if there were to be four different patient IDs, how would I display the shared Name with all 4 patientIDs next to each other in the table. However, in this instance, I do not need to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you expect no more than two patient ID values, then a simple aggregation can work here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT NAME
    FROM PATIENT
    GROUP BY NAME
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 AND COUNT(DISTINCT WARDNO) < 2
)

SELECT
    NAME,
    MIN(PATIENTID) AS PatientID1,
    MAX(PATIENTID) AS PatientID2
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    NAME;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Tim. That aggregation did work and I did a little tweak to make it a lot cleaner. It works to display just the two PatientIDs which is what I need for now.
My new query is as follows

```
SELECT pt.NAME, MIN(pt.PATIENTID) AS PAT, MAX(pt.PATIENTID) AS PAT
FROM PATIENT pt
GROUP BY pt.NAME
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 AND COUNT(DISTINCT pt.WARDNO) < 2
```

However, if I do have multiple PatientIDs I am curious what I would do.

Answer (score 0):

> I have to select which wards have patients with the same last name.

Assuming patients are not duplicated, you can get the patient/ward combinations as:

```
select p.wardno, p.name, count(*)
from patient p
group by p.wardno, p.name
having count(*) >= 2;
```

If you only want the wards, then you have one of the rare situations where `select distinct` and `group by` are appropriate:

```
select distinct p.wardno
from patient p
group by p.wardno, p.name
having count(*) >= 2;
```